# Lotus Notes 7.5 calendar view default to "all calendar entries"

Tags: lotus-notes

When I clicked the calendar bookmark, calendar starts with "all calendar entries" view each time. How to change it to Month view instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working off a local, you could recreate the local from the server copy.  If it's a server copy that's messed up, you'll probably have to work through your helpdesk/notes admins. Usually for issues like this, the first thing I'd try would be to replace the mailfile design.